# how to fix -[__NSCFString gtm_stringByUnescapingFromURLArgument] in google+ authentication

Tags: iphone, authentication, ios6, google-plus, social-networking

I  am trying to create an application that retrieves the current user's email id, user id, user name from his google+ account. The part of the code is as follows,

```
- (IBAction)googleSigninBtnTapped:(id)sender
{

    [GPPSignInButton class];
    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MY APP ID"];
    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.delegate = self;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = YES;
    signIn.actions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      @"http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
                      @"http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity",
                      @"http://schemas.google.com/CheckInActivity",
                      @"http://schemas.google.com/CommentActivity",
                      @"http://schemas.google.com/CreateActivity",
                      @"http://schemas.google.com/ListenActivity",
                      @"http://schemas.google.com/ReserveActivity",
                      @"http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity",
                      nil];
    [signIn trySilentAuthentication];
}

(void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError )error 
{
 if (error) 
{
 NSLog(@"Status: Authentication error: %@", error); 
}
 else
 {
 NSLog(@"Status: Authenticated");
 NSLog(@"Email: %@",[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail); 
GTLServicePlus plusService = [[[GTLServicePlus alloc] init] autorelease]; 
plusService.retryEnabled = YES; 
[plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication]; 
GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"]; 
[plusService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLPlusPerson *person, NSError *error)
 { 
if (error)
 { 
GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error); 
}
 else
 { 
[person retain]; 
NSLog(@"%@", person.displayName); 
NSLog(@"%@", person.identifier); 
}
 }]; 
} 
}
```

But when i am trying to execute my app, it gets crashed, saying that

'-[__NSCFString gtm_stringByUnescapingFromURLArgument]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9e435b0'

Can anybody help me on this...!!!

Thanks In Advance!!!

Answer (score 5):

Yep, you need the -ObjC linker flag in, it's not finding one of the categories from the GoogleOpenSource framework.

See Step 3 in the setup guide: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started#step_3_initialize_the_google_client

Basically, in Other Linker Flags, add -ObjC (capitalisation is important, note!). Also make sure you have included both GooglePlus and GoogleOpenSource frameworks in your project.

Comment: Thanks Dude... But I already entered the -ObjC in other linker flags area... Actually i did this code with the reference of GOOGLE's video that explains step by step setup... Thats my problem now.. I cant find where i committed a mistake..

Comment: And you definitely imported both frameworks (googleopensource and googleplus) as well?

Comment: ya... i did... let me state what i have done. 1.inserted necessary frameworks 2.entered -ObjC 3.entered bundleid & redirect url 4.inserted code... thats it...

Comment: Odd! Can you go to your project, check the build phases tab, and under "Link Binary With Libraries" check the GoogelOpenSource.framework is in there?

Answer (score 0):

Add with _objc the other flag called -lc++